# RemoteViews - void method setRemoteAdapter

Tags: android, widget

I'm trying to implement a widget, with a layout that has a GridView. My onUpdate method inside the widget class is:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);

                    /**views.setRemoteAdapter(..)**/

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainAppDelegate.class);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I call **views.setRemoteAdapter(..)**  java doesn't know what method it is. Why is that happening? Do I need to upgrade the sdk? Also, it doesn't recognise **setBundle() method**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setRemoteAdapter()` is only available on API Level 11. You need to have your build target set to API Level 11 or higher to compile using this method, and you need to take care to ensure that this code then only runs on API Level 11 or higher devices.

Comment: I just found out, thank you for your response. Do you know another method to set up a gridview adapter without using this function?

Comment: @Radu: You cannot have a `GridView` in a `RemoteViews` except on API Level 11 or higher, in which case you have `setRemoteAdapter()`.